# meaning of this code :for(i=0;argv[1][i]!='\0';i++)

Tags: c, string, command-line, argv

I found this code from book named "Learn C the hard way", but I am could not understand the meaning and purpose of :

```
for(i=0;argv[1][i]!='\0';i++){
    char letter=argv[1][i];
```

Comment: Read the whole book, and you'll understand.

Comment: This code is incomplete and doesn't make sense

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about it?  The loop structure?  The array subscript?  The declaration within the loop?

Comment: I do not understand how this code gonna work,as I am just beginner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

main with parameters according to the C Standard is declared like

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
```

that is equivalent to

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
```

that is `argv` points to first element of an array of pointers to first characters of strings.

Thus `argv[1]`  is pointer to first character of the second parameter (the first parameter is the program name). For example `*argv[1]` or `argv[1][0]` is the first character of a zero-terminated string.

For example if your program is run like

```
your_program Hello
```

then the command line parameter is passed to the program like string `"Hello"`. And this loop

```
for(i=0;argv[1][i]!='\0';i++){
    char letter=argv[1][i];
```

traverses the string until the terminating zero is encountered.

You can output all parameters character by character the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) 
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; argv[i][j] != '\0'; j++ ) putchar( argv[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`argv[1]` is the second string in the string array `argv`, and strings are character arrays so `argv[1][0]` is the **first character in the second string**, `argv[1][1]` is the **second character in the second string** and so on.

Comment: Be careful because argv[1] is the first parameter, argv[0] is the program name

Answer (score -1):

For each letter in the argument passed to the program it creates a variable called letter with that value.
I think it is used in the following rows of the for cycle.